# How to identify the program that uses most bandwidth?

Tags: networking, monitoring, bandwidth

How can I know which application is using the most network bandwidth? I saw some graph from KDE's network monitor, but don't know which process did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, iftop can not show which processes are using the bandwidth. If you need this information, you should check out [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You have an [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) utility.

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/how-should-i-determine-the-current-network-utilization), there's also `ifstat`.